# HQL-запрос к Базе Данных работает не корректно с OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hql

У меня есть две сущности: `Customer` и `CustomerOrder`. Зависимость между ними One-to-Many. В файле с репозиторием я создаю запрос, который должен:

- Возвращает Customer с CustomerOrders, которые в поле `active` имеют значение `true` и пользователь существует
- Возвращает Customer БЕЗ CustomerOrders, если пользователь существует, но у него нет прикрепленных customerOrders
- Возвращает Customer БЕЗ CustomerOrders, если пользователь существует, но у него все значения `active` равны `false`.

Запрос, который представлен ниже, он работает с первым пунктом из списка выше, но не с двумя оставшимися. Как правильно должен писаться запрос к БД, чтобы все пункты могли выполняться?

Запрос:

```java
@Query("from Customer cs left join fetch cs.customerOrder custOrd " +
       "where custOrd.active = true")
Customer findByCustomerId(Long id);
```

Ниже будет приведен пример таблиц и ответы в зависимости от запроса.

---

### Сущности:

**Customer.java:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table
@ToString
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "customer",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<CustomerOrder> customerOrders = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addCustomerOrder(CustomerOrder customerOrder) {
        customerOrders.add(customerOrder);
        customerOrder.setCustomer(this);
    }

    public void removeCustomerOrder(CustomerOrder customerOrder) {
        customerOrders.remove(customerOrder);
        customerOrder.setCustomer(null);
    }

    // equals() и hashCode()
}
```

**CustomerOrder.java:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomerOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private boolean active;

    private String orderNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    // equals() и hashCode()

}
```

---

### Пример таблиц:

**Customer:**

```
table: customer
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | surname |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | John | Smith   |
|  2 | Mary | Johnson |
|  3 | Sam  | Brown   |
+----+------+---------+
```

**CustomerOrder:**

```
table: customer_order
+----+--------+--------------+-------------+
| id | active | order_number | customer_id |
+----+--------+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | true   | AE123        |           1 |
|  2 | false  | AE456        |           1 |
|  3 | false  | AE567        |           2 |
|  4 | false  | AE890        |           2 |
+----+--------+--------------+-------------+
```

---

### Результаты:

findByCustomerId(1) [John]:

> возвращается Customer `John` и прикрепленных к нему `CustomerOrder` с id: 2

findByCustomerId(2) [Mary]:

> возвращается Customer `Mary`. customer.getCustomerOrder().size() должен быть равен 0.

findByCustomerId(3) [Sam]:

> возвращается Customer `Sam`. customer.getCustomerOrder().size() должен быть равен 0.

Answer (score 2):

Вы выбрали не тот инструмент, решение задачи лежит в другой плоскости.

Для начала надо разобраться с требованиями. Проведем эксперимент: будем последовательно увеличивать колличество `CustomerOrder` и смотреть как это влияет на конечный результат.

1. Предположим сначала, что у `Customer` нет ни одного `CustomerOrder`. В таком случае данный `Customer` должен быть выбран по п.2 требований.
2. Добавим к данному `Customer` один `CustomerOrder`:
   Если у этого `CustomerOrder` `active == false`, то данный `Customer` должен быть выбран по п.3 требований.
   Если у этого `CustomerOrder` `active == true`, то данный `Customer` должен быть выбран по п.1 требований.
3. Продолжим и дальше добавлять новые `CustomerOrder`. Предположим, что у `Customer` уже есть N `CustomerOrder` и для всех из них верно, что `active == false`. Данный `Customer` выбирается по п.3 требований. Теперь добавим новый `CustomerOrder`.
   Если у нового `CustomerOrder` `active == false`, то данный `Customer` должен быть выбран по п.3 тербований.
   Если у нового `CustomerOrder` `active == true`, то данный `Customer` должен быть выбран по п.1 требований.

Становится понятно, что не имеет значения какое колличество `CustomerOrder` (и с какими атрибутами) есть у `Customer`, любой `Customer` подойдет под требования запроса.
Поэтому задача сводится не к поиску `Customer`, а к фильтрации `CustomerOrder`. Сама фильтрация может быть решена множеством путей:

1. с использованием `@Where` из Hibernate:

```java
public class Customer {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "customer",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<CustomerOrder> customerOrders = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addCustomerOrder(CustomerOrder customerOrder) {
        customerOrders.add(customerOrder);
        customerOrder.setCustomer(this);
    }

    public void removeCustomerOrder(CustomerOrder customerOrder) {
        customerOrders.remove(customerOrder);
        customerOrder.setCustomer(null);
    }

    // Дополнительная readonly-коллекция заказов, удовлетворяющих дополнительным условиям
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Where(clause = "active = true")
    private List<CustomerOrder> customerOrdersSample;

    // ...

}
```

2. запрос с фильтрацией на уровне бизнес-логики:

```java
public class CustomerService {

    // ...

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    // ...

    public List<CustomerOrder> getCustomerOrdersByCustomerId(Long customerId) {
        return customerRepository
                .findById(customerId)
                .map(Customer::getCustomerOrders)
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                .stream()
                .filter(CustomerOrder::isActive)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Запрос в репозиторий с `CustomerOrder` на выбор всех сущностей с `active == true` и принадлежащих определенному `Customer` тоже будет являться решением  задачи.